# searching google images from python

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-scraping

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import urllib
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse

def getPic(search):
    search = search.replace(" ","%20")
    try:
            browser = mechanize.Browser()
            browser.set_handle_robots(False)
            browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla')]

            htmltext = browser.open("https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1855&bih=990&q=" + search + "&oq=" +search)
            img_url = []
            formatted_images = []
            soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
            results = soup.findAll("a")
            for r in results:
                    try:
                            if "imgres?imgurl" in r['href']:
                                    img_url.append(r['href'])
                    except:
                            a=0
            for im in img_url:
                    refer_url = urlparse(str(img_url[0]))
                    return refer_url.query.split("&")[0].replace("imgurl=","")
            return  formatted_images


    except:
            print "error"
print getPic("occupy wall street")
```

Instead of getting the link of an image as output I'm getting "[]" as an output.Can someone figure out what's the problem with my code.

Comment: Google doesn't like bots. For example: real browser doesn't use 'User-Agent:Mozilla' and Google knows this. Print `soup` to see what you get from server.

Comment: Why you use `return` in `for im in img_url` ? Where do you append something to `formatted_images` ?

Answer (score 0):

Google sends `"imgres?imgurl"` only to browser with JavaScript
but `mechanize.Browser()` is like browser without JavaScript.

Turn off JavaScript in your browser and see HTML send by Google.